# Ubuntu USB error

Tags: usb, usb-installation

I am trying to make a portable Ubuntu USB. I want it to be able to be used in other computers and still have my settings. So I'm at the screen where it show the partition table for the installation and where you select your USB. I am not entirely sure what you do here but I selected the /dev/sdb1 fat32 option.
Then I chose my USB for the device for boot load installation. I clicked install now, and it says No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu.  What do I do???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the partition you want to install the system on (in this case it'll be /dev/sdb probably) and click on "change" button, then choose "/" as mount point.